# Updating a textView after certain time elapsed

Tags: android

I am using System.NanoTime to track elapsed time, however it does not update on the UI. Following is my code:

I am however doing everything in the `onCreate()` method, the approach I've taken might not be robust, but that's where I want more ideas.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    // ... the code being measured ...
    long estimatedTime = (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000000;
    System.out.println(""+estimatedTime);
    while (estimatedTime <= 100){
        System.out.println(""+estimatedTime);

        if(estimatedTime == 1){
            TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
            tx.setText("Preparing"); 

        }
        if(estimatedTime == 2){
            TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
            tx.setText("Inatializing"); 

        }
        if(estimatedTime == 3){
            TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
            tx.setText("Preparing to install"); 

        }
        if(estimatedTime == 4){
            TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
            tx.setText("Installing"); 

        }
        if(estimatedTime == 5){
            TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
            tx.setText("Installed"); 

        }
        if(estimatedTime == 6){
            TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
            tx.setText("Unzipping packages..."); 

        }


        estimatedTime = (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000000;
    }

}
```

Comment: are you getting any kind of error ?

Comment: No there is no error, SOP is running fine, but I am not getting any value in the textview.

Comment: onCreate will be called only once when the activity is created. So only once the textview item will be updated. Use a handler, countdowntimer or asynctask to do your requirement

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can try:

```
tx.postInvalidate();
```

where tx is your TextView object

after this line:

```
estimatedTime = (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000000;
```

But you should all this code which is below "while" put into Thread.
Example:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //your code here
        }
    }).start();
```

UPDATE:
Update main thread you can using this:

```
YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //here set text into textView
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, it should by like this that you put all code below "long startTime = System.nanoTime();" in thread. And when you done this you can update UI by ".postInvalidate();" or just by runOnUiThread()

Comment: android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Answer (score 1):

You cant do that in the UI thread as its blocking. You should move that to an AsyncTask.

Answer (score 1):

Use another thread and call runOnUiThread method and pass the object of that thread.like following

```
Thread th=new Thread(new Runnable() {



        @Override
        public void run() {
            //put your code here
while (estimatedTime <= 100){
Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println(""+estimatedTime);

        if(estimatedTime == 1){
            TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
            tx.setText("Preparing"); 

        }
        if(estimatedTime == 2){
            TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
            tx.setText("Inatializing"); 

        }
        if(estimatedTime == 3){
            TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
            tx.setText("Preparing to install"); 

        }
        if(estimatedTime == 4){
            TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
            tx.setText("Installing"); 

        }
        if(estimatedTime == 5){
            TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
            tx.setText("Installed"); 

        }
        if(estimatedTime == 6){
            TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
            tx.setText("Unzipping packages..."); 

        }


        estimatedTime = (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000000;
        }
    });
```

runOnUiThread(th);

Comment: Can you explain more please? I am new to Java and Android.

Comment: also there is no  Thread.sleep(1000); method thats why it just do not show you any output

Answer (score 1):

Better to use Handler to delay some task...

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){ 
    public void Run(){
        //Put your code here. Code will execute after 1000ms
    }
}, 1000);
```